# Multivariable limit $\lim\limits_{(x,y,z)\to(0,0,0)}\frac{3xyz}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Can anybody give me a hint on how to bound 
$$\frac{3xyz}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$

I'm trying to prove that it converges to zero. Thanks!

Comment: This is the second question that you've asked recently that seems to have the same idea. Perhaps it might be good to understand one before asking the next.

Comment: Yes, I thought of using the AMGM inequality like the question that I've already asked, I just wanted to find another bound. For some reason I don't like to take the limit of an square root. Is not that I didn't understood, I just was looking for other methods to do it.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** You can use [spherical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system):

> $$ x=r \, \sin\theta \, \cos\varphi \\
>    y=r \, \sin\theta \, \sin\varphi \\
>     z=r \, \cos\theta , $$

where $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$, $0\leq \theta \leq \pi$, and $0\leq \phi \leq 2\pi$.

**Note:** consider taking the limit as $r\to 0$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Note that $f(x,y,z)\to0$ if and only if $\lvert f(x,y,z)\rvert\to0$.  Now, 
$$
\left\lvert\frac{3xyz}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right\rvert=\frac{3\lvert x\rvert\,\lvert y\rvert\,\lvert z\rvert}{x^2+y^2+z^2}.
$$
Now, note that
$$
\lvert x\rvert=\sqrt{x^2}\leq\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2},
$$
and similarly $\lvert y\rvert,\lvert z\rvert\leq\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$.

Comment: Yes! I did that, and then I got stuck... could you give me a tiny tiny hint on how to keep going?

Comment: @LunaSage There really isn't much more to do.  Are you trying to do this based on $\epsilon-\delta$ proof, or just squeeze theorem?

Comment: Squeeze theorem

Comment: Should I use it on the delta-epsilon proof?

Comment: @LunaSage Well, in this case, they're basically the same. Squeeze theorem is fine.  The inequality above gives you $0\leq\lvert f(x,y,z)\rvert\leq\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$, where $f$ is your function.  But obviously $0\to0$ as $(x,y,z)\to(0,0,0)$; further, $x^2+y^2+z^2\to0$ (it is a polynomial), so that $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\to0$ as well.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** The AM-GM gives
$$
\left(x^2y^2z^2\right)^{1/3}\le\frac13\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)
$$
then
$$
\left|\frac{3xyz}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right|\le\left|\frac{xyz}{\left(x^2y^2z^2\right)^{1/3}}\right|=|xyz|^{1/3}
$$

---

**Alternate Approach**

Easily, we have
$$
\begin{align}
x^2&\le x^2+y^2+z^2\\
y^2&\le x^2+y^2+z^2\\
z^2&\le x^2+y^2+z^2
\end{align}
$$
Multiplying and taking the square root yields
$$
|xyz|\le\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{3/2}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\frac{3|xyz|}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\le3\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{1/2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{3} \geq |xyz|^{2/3}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\left|\frac{3xyz}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right|=\frac{|3xyz|}{\|(x,y,z)\|^2}\le
3\frac{\|(x,y,z)\|^3}{\|(x,y,z)\|^2}=3\|(x,y,z)\|
$$